# "Wait Until Page Contains" keyword doesn't work on RobotFramework-appium

Tags: ios, appium, robotframework

I'm using appium (1.6.3) library of RobotFramework 3.0 on Mac desktop (Sierra, 10.12.3) to automate real iOS device (platform version 10.2.1). I'm using Xcode version 8.2.1 and XCUI Test Driver version 2.4.2.

Test Script:

```
Launch Application    ${AppName}   
Wait Until Page Contains    Inbox
```

Result:

```
Text "Inbox" did not appear in 10 seconds
```

I have noticed that none of the wait keywords is properly working. The "inbox" actually was visible just after 1-2 seconds but still appium couldn't identify the text. Appium doesn't intelligently updates the screen to get the page source and then verify if the element is available on the screen. The temporary solution I found is introducing sleep time (which is not efficient).

Question: Is there any way I can make my script efficient and use wait keywords instead Sleep?

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question but in first place I'd recommend to use timeout with Wait Until Page Contains

Comment: This won't be a final solution, and this seems to be an old question. but I will suggest making use of `Set Appium Timeout` this will help, however, I believe the best way will use the capabilities, is something like `appium:appWaitForLaunch` on your `Open Application`